# How do I give PHP permissions to run PDFTK?

Tags: php, permissions, pdftk

PDFTK run from the command line:

```
$ pdftk
SYNOPSIS
       pdftk <input PDF files | - | PROMPT>
        [ input_pw <input PDF owner passwords | PROMPT> ]
```

PDFTK run from PHP:

```
HI
<br>
<?php echo shell_exec('ls'); ?>
<br>
<?php echo shell_exec('pdftk'); ?>
```

prints

```
HI 
css favicon.ico files images index.php js test.php
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Is your PHP in safemode? `shell_exec` won't work in that case.

Comment: that's what the ls test was for. turned out being a path issue w/ the mac binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a path issue, not permissions (it should only require read permission for input file, and read-write for output file).  Do:

```
which pdftk
```

to get the path, then put that in `shell_exec`.

Comment: This is correct, the mac binary is installed in a way that it can be run from the terminal but not accessed by PHP. the way to call pdftk on mac is apparently "/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/bin/pdftk"